# Deducing template parameters from std::function

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

I'm writing a little class using a static template member function trying to map a std::function with its parameters :

```
class test
{
public:
    template <typename R, typename... Args>
    static double exec(std::function<R(Args...)> func, Args && ... args) {
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        // do something
        return 0.0;
    }
};
```

Supposing I have these trivial functions :

- `void f1() { ; }`
- `int f2(int v) { return v; }`
- `double f3(int v1, float v2) { return (double)v1 * (double)v2; }`

I would like to call my `test::exec` function like this :

```
test::exec(f1);
test::exec(f2, 4);
test::exec(f3, 1, 3.14f);
```

I'm using Visual Studio and I get this error for the second case (f2) :

```
error C2672: 'test::exec': no matching overloaded function found
error C2784: 'double test::exec(std::function<_Ret(_Types...)>,Args &&...)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<_Ret(_Types...)>' from 'int (__cdecl *)(int)'
```

Nevertheless, it work if I specify the the types in the template signature : `test::exec<int, int>(sq, 4);`  Obviously, I would like to avoid that. Also, I don't know how to formulate the call to f1 with this syntax.

Is it possible to achieve this goal without specifying the signature of the template parameters?

Comment: @NathanOliver That target doesn't look right. The OP is not using a lambda at all.

Comment: Why are you trying to deduce a `std::function`? Why not accept a function pointer instead?

Comment: Is there a reason `exec` wants to take `std::function`, and not just any callable? `template <typename F, typename... Args> double exec(F func, Args&& ... args)` should work the way you expect.

Comment: @cigien lambda, function pointer, doesn't matter. They aren't a `std::function`, so the inner types can't be deduced.  That's the gist of the dupe.

Comment: @NathanOliver Maybe so, but the solution there is not appropriate for the OP's question. Are you suggesting that an answer should be added on that target? In fact, that solution shows how to deduce the `R`, since the OP there needs it. As far as this question goes, Igor's solution seems the simplest, since OP doesn't seem to need to know `R` at all.

Comment: @Igor There is no reason, I thought I was using callable with function. My mistake. Your answer is what I was looking for. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can't deduce the `std:function` arguments and return type, because you are not passing `exec` a `std::function` at all.

---

Instead of a `std::function`, you can just make `exec` accept an arbitrary type of callable (which includes functions), and let the compiler deduce its signature:

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
static double exec(Func func, Args && ... args);
```

---

If you do need to know the return type of the function that you pass to `exec`, you can do it like this:

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
static double exec(Func func, Args && ... args) 
{
  using R = decltype(func(args...));
  // ...
}
```

The answer is adapted from @IgorTandetnik's comments.

Comment: With `typename Func` version, if you need to know the return type, it's readily available as `decltype(func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Good point, I added that, thanks. I'll leave the function pointer option in there as well.

Comment: `R(*func)(Args...), Args && ... args` is problematic as `Args` have to be deduce the same way (which is also problematic in OP's version). Make one of them non deducible, of use other template args.

Comment: @Jarod42 Deduction seems to [work](https://godbolt.org/z/47befq) just fine.

Comment: Try to pass lvalue or `const char*` for `std::string` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yznrcf).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, you're right, I didn't think of that, thanks. I've edited the answer to remove that option, since fixing it is not worth the effort for the question. Now it's not really very different from the target the question was originally closed with, apart from the different ways to compute `R`. Go ahead and dupe-hammer if you think it's close enough.